# Deserializing JSON: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character

Tags: json, f#, json.net

**Problem:**

I just can't figure out what's wrong with the JSON below.

**Error:**

```
'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'
```

**Test:**

I ran a JSON validation tool on it and it passed as valid JSON. However, I continue to receive a base-64 conversion error.

```
{
  "Courier": {
    "CourierId": "e168d837-0f0e-4f61-8a3d-725b53d11277",
    "Name": "Jeremy Bot",
    "ProfileImage": "undefined_image",
    "LastLocation": {
      "Latitude": 25.87427,
      "Longitude": -80.12173
    },
    "IsSubscribed": true,
    "Timestamp": "2020-04-11T19:11:21.1821483-04:00"
  },
  "Request": {
    "RequestId": "78d31dab-e631-4f95-aa31-d95b218a1850",
    "Customer": {
      "CustomerId": "some_customer_id",
      "Name": "John Doe",
      "Location": {
        "Latitude": 25.87427,
        "Longitude": -80.12173
      },
      "Phone": "(XXX-XXX-XXXX)"
    },
    "Carriers": {
      "Restaurants": [],
      "Stores": []
    }
  },
  "ETA": "30 minutes"
}
```

**Test 2:**

I thought that the cause could be a negative number in my JSON.

However, the following didn't work:

```
let handleNegativeValues = JsonSerializerSettings(FloatParseHandling=FloatParseHandling.Decimal)

let payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'T>(json, handleNegativeValues)
```

**Cause:**

Here's the code that I execute which results in the error:

```
let payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'T>(json)
```

**Appendix:**

Here's the root type that I'm trying to deserialize to:

```
[<DataContract>]
type CourierAcceptedSubmission = {

    [<field: DataMember(Name="Courier")>]
    Courier  : Courier

    [<field: DataMember(Name="Request")>]
    Request  : Request

    [<field: DataMember(Name="ETA")>]
    ETA  : string
}
```

Here's the type that contains ProfileImage:

```
[<DataContract>]
type Courier = {

    [<field: DataMember(Name="CourierId")>]
    CourierId    : string

    [<field: DataMember(Name="Name")>]
    Name         : string

    [<field: DataMember(Name="ProfileImage")>]
    ProfileImage : string

    [<field: DataMember(Name="LastLocation")>]
    LastLocation : Coordinate

    [<field: DataMember(Name="IsSubscribed")>]
    IsSubscribed : bool

    [<field: DataMember(Name="Timestamp")>]
    Timestamp    : DateTime
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the class `T` you are trying to deserialize into?  Most likely one of the properties is declared as `byte[]` instead of `string` and that is causing the problem.

Comment: Likely the `ProfileImage`.

Comment: ProfileImage is of type string though. It's not a byte array. I could demo this on Twitch if you'd like...

Comment: What about the rest of the classes, e.g. Request and Carriers?  Any byte arrays there?  As an aside, those don't look like C# class definitions.  Are you using F#?

Comment: Yes. It's F#. There's no bye arrays anywhere.

Comment: I take that back... I do have a byte array for ProfileImage on the receiver side. I was checking the server def.

Comment: @BrianRogers - You were right. It's resolved feel free to post it as the answer.

Comment: OK, answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json.Net handles byte arrays by automatically converting them to and from base-64 encoded strings.  So if you are deserializing JSON into a class that has a property declared as `byte[]` but the corresponding string value in the JSON is not base-64 encoded, for example `"undefined_image"`, that will cause the error you are seeing.

The easiest fix is to change the type of the offending property from `byte[]` to `string`.  However, if you have a situation where the JSON will sometimes contain valid base-64 strings and sometimes not, and you do want it to be a `byte[]` to handle the data for the valid case, you would need to create a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to handle that property.

Answer (score 0):

Though its bit late but i think someone else may face similar issue, so writing down solution which worked for me.

Convert byte[] of image in string by using ASCIIEncoding:

```
using System.Text;
...

...
ProfileImage = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(byte_array_of_image);
```